# FBWC capacitor pack hp Proliant DL380e Gen8 is broken down

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, configuration, hardware, hp

I have a HP server Proliant DL380e Gen8 and it presented a problem that does not turn on the server and the system health LED gets flashing red quickly. After searching for information on the internet I found information pointing to the FBWC capacitor pack. I wonder if there is any effective testing to confirm if this is really the defective part (capacitor 17F 5.4V)
Has anyone been through this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: If possible, you can remove the RAID controller and try to start up the server. If it  starts, than you found the problem (the RAID card).

Comment: @shodanshok is right, BTW, how about an electrical circuit tester? You already know it should be around 5.4V. Good luck.

Comment: @shodanshok, many thanks for your information, but if I remove the RAID controller and try to start up the server the device  doesn't works and the system health LED gets flashing red slowly (1/s).

Comment: @Marco, many thanks for your information. I'll test it this way.